# hp4500 officejet not detected by Simple Scan, cannot access modem config. page or connect to wireless

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, usb, hp, scanner

I upgraded to 10.04 from 8.04 in September. When I try to use Simple Scan it says "No scanners detected". `sane-find-scanner` detects my printer/scanner.

UPDATE: `lsusb` now detects my scanner after I installed hplip from the hp website.

```
administrator@snoopy:~$ lsusb
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:4712 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo sane-find-scanner`:

```
# sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
# result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
# scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

# No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
# you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [HP], product=0x4712 [Officejet 4500 G510a-f]) at libusb:001:005
# Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
# SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

# Not checking for parallel port scanners.

# Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
# can't be detected by this program.
```

--- The info below was appended

Martin Owens, it's definitely not impossible as it's still happening. From /var/log/syslog

```
Nov  1 13:21:14 snoopy kernel: [163980.380089] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Nov  1 13:21:14 snoopy kernel: [163980.514030] usb 1-3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Nov  1 13:21:16 snoopy udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1
Nov  1 13:21:16 snoopy udev-configure-printer: parent devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3
Nov  1 13:21:16 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Device vendor/product is 03F0:4712
Nov  1 13:21:16 snoopy udev-configure-printer: MFG:HP MDL:Officejet 4500 G510a-f SERN:CN049F20C905H2 serial:CN049F20C905H2
Nov  1 13:21:16 snoopy kernel: [163982.225839] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x4712
Nov  1 13:21:16 snoopy kernel: [163982.225904] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
Nov  1 13:21:16 snoopy udev-configure-printer: add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/usb/lp0
Nov  1 13:21:18 snoopy kernel: [163984.395465] usb 1-3: usbfs: interface 1 claimed by usblp while 'usb' sets config #1
Nov  1 13:21:19 snoopy hp[2987]: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: SERN fields match
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI match: usb://HP/Officejet%204500%20G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: SERN fields match
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI match: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: parent devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510a f s
erial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://HP/Officejet%204500%20G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500
 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f has matching device URI
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510
a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f has matching device URI
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510a f s
erial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://HP/Officejet%204500%20G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500
 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f_2 has matching device URI
Nov  1 13:21:20 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f_2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510
a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f_2 has matching device URI
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost:631/printers/Officejet_4500_G510a-f_2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: hpfax:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: hpfax usb officejet 4
500 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://HP/Officejet%204500%20G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500
 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510
a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: hpfax:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: hpfax usb officejet 4
500 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://HP/Officejet%204500%20G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500
 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510
a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: hpfax:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: hpfax usb officejet 4
500 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://HP/Officejet%204500%20G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500
 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510
a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: cups-pdf:/, normalized: cups pdf
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://HP/Officejet%204500%20G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500
 g510a f serial cn049f20c905h2
Nov  1 13:21:21 snoopy udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: hp:/usb/Officejet_4500_G510a-f?serial=CN049F20C905H2, normalized: officejet 4500 g510
a f serial cn049f20c905h2
```

Don't see anything in dmesg log.
from dmesg | grep usb

```
[    0.124495] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.124519] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.124574] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.312547] usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    0.313151] usb usb2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    0.313627] usb usb3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    0.314062] usb usb4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    0.314486] usb usb5: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    0.900795] usb 3-2: new low speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 2
[    1.122525] usb 3-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    1.429716] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
[    1.431864] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.433611] usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
[    1.560705] input: Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input3
[    1.560882] microsoft 0003:045E:00DB.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input0
[    1.584491] input: Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.1/input/input4
[    1.584673] microsoft 0003:045E:00DB.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Natural® Ergonomic Keyboard 4000] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input1
[163980.380089] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[163980.514030] usb 1-3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[163982.225839] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x4712
[163982.225904] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[163984.395465] usb 1-3: usbfs: interface 1 claimed by usblp while 'usb' sets config #1
```

Also I am unable to access my modem configuration at http://192.168.1.254/ as I am continuously prompted for my user name and password. I was able to access the page before the upgrade. My ISP confirmed I have the correct info. I was also unable to connect to a wireless internet connection i.e. was continuously prompted for password. So could there be a problem with the software used to communicate with devices?

I know dbus was part of the upgrade & I think I installed a new version from the source (and some other packages) when I didn't have an internet connection and was trying to complete the upgrade. I also followed tips to fix a common problem with the password ring. Should I re-install the dbus package or some other packages?

Aquaherd, my processor: model name : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.40GHz stepping : 4 cpu MHz : 2394.331 cache size : 256 KB 
I think my computer is several years old. I'm not aware that there's any difference in the USB ports, I am able to use them with my camera and my usb drive. Maybe it changes to 2.0 once a device is plugged in.

Comment: You seem to have four USB1.1 but only one 2.0 capable hub - how old and which CPU is your machine?

Comment: I have merged your accounts and merged your answer back into your question.

Comment: Can you check in your bios for an option similar to "legacy usb" - try switching this value off or on.

Comment: Switched the "legacy usb" in the bios to disabled from enabled and still have the same problem.

Comment: hp4500 is HP Officejet 4500, HP Designjet 4500 or HP Scanjet 4500?

Comment: Added officejet to title. The output from sudo sane-find-scanner and in the syslog above also say officejet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Scan and `lsusb` detects the scanner after doing the following:

1. Uninstall the hplip installed from the hp website by entering `sudo make uninstall` and then `make clean` in the hp directory.
2. Install hplip and hplip-cups using System>Administration>Synaptic Package Manager. In my case, before clicking 'apply' in the package manager, I had to go to Settings>Repositories and uncheck 'Cdrom with Ubuntu 10.04' in the 'Installable from CD-ROM/DVD' box at the bottom in order for the necessary packages to be downloaded.
3. Run `hp-check -r`
4. In my case, the output said that the user 'root' needed to be in the 'lp' and 'lp-admin' groups so I used `usermod -G group-name user-name` to add 'root' to those groups.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible, it might be that your usb device has a hardware fault and is reporting badly or disappearing from the bus when you do lsusb. you should check the logs in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/dmesg` to see what might be happening when you plug the printer/scanner in.

This is probably not a driver issue I suspect.